# When I combine ActionBarSherlock and SlidingMenu,SLIDING_MENU not work correctly?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

When I use SlidingMenu and  ActionBarSherlock together, I notice that When I call

```
attachToActivity(.. SLIDING_CONTENT ..)
```

it not work.

I think it must because the ActionBarSherlock changed the THEME to NO TITLE BAR.

question: How can I make SLIDING_CONTENT work ?

This is my onCreate function (the class extended from SherlockFragmentActivity)

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // start SlidingMenu configuration
    mSlidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    mSlidingMenu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    mSlidingMenu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    mSlidingMenu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    mSlidingMenu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    mSlidingMenu.setMenu(R.layout.sliding_menu);
    mMenuView = mSlidingMenu.getMenu();
    mSlidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    mSlidingMenu.setOnClosedListener(this);
```

Comment: Post your `onCreate(Bundle s)` function where you instantiate and setup the ActionBar and the SlidingMenu.

Comment: What does your LogCat say?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) with ActionBarSherlock, then you'll have to change all Activities in the library to SherlockActivity, all FragmentActivites to SherlockFragmentActivity and all ListActivities to SherlockListActivity etc.
Change [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingActivity.java), [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingListActivity.java), [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingFragmentActivity.java) and [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingMapActivity.java).

Comment: This is not the case with the latest code for SlidingMenu. He added an attachToActivity function that allows you to attach to an activity of arbitrary class. I've just confirmed with a basic SherlockActivity.

Comment: Could you tell me how to change?